AVR show an error with the delay function
I have next question:
I run my program and i get this error:
At top level:  pdi/xmega_pdi_nvm.c:530:25: warning: 'xnvm_erase_application_flash_page' defined but not used [-Wunused-function]   static enum status_code xnvm_erase_application_flash_page(uint32_t address, uint8_t *dat_buf, uint16_t length)                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
make clean all -C ../w1222 MODEL=100.w1222-default  
make[1]: *** ../w1222: No such file or directory. Stop.  
make: *** [Makefile:794: hheld.hex] Error 2  
elena@Elena:~/test2/pclw1222testrig$ 

When I go to Makefile line 794 in my code I have this:
**# Build the target image flash and eeprom files ready for embedding

$(W1222_FLASH) $(W1222_EEPROM):

    $(MAKE) clean all -C $(W1222_DIR) MODEL=$(MODEL)

    cp $(W1222_DIR)/$(W1222_FLASH) $(W1222_FLASH)

    cp $(W1222_DIR)/$(W1222_EEPROM) $(W1222_EEPROM)**

Display compiler version information.
The line 794 is:
$(MAKE) clean all -C $(W1222_DIR) MODEL=$(MODEL)
that directories are define

ifeq ($(TARGET_BOARD), w1299) 
W1222_DIR := ../w1299 
W1222_FLASH := w1299.hex 
W1222_EEPROM := w1299.eep 
SPIPROG_USE_PDI := 1 
else 
W1222_DIR := ../w1222 
W1222_FLASH := hheld.hex 
W1222_EEPROM := hheld.eep 
SPIPROG_USE_PDI := 0 
endif

I'm working with w1222
Any idea why I have this problem with the directory? They can't find the file or directory.

File ../w1222 cannot be found. So you have to find out why it does not exists, or why the Makefile thinks it should exist.
